# Dynamically fill json object with strings and string arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following problem. I am new to json and javascript and i need to dynamically build a json object and feed it with strings. The incoming strings are not sorted so it should be possible to make a string array. I came up with this design but i am getting an error.

```
 addToDumpObject: function (type, v, dump) {

        if (v instanceof A.entity.Entity) {
            dump.type.push(v.toString());
        } else if (v instanceof jQuery) {
            dump.type.push(v);
        } else if ($.isArray(v)) {
            for (var i in v) {
                A.util.addToDumpObject(type, v[i], dump);
            }
            return;
        } else {
        }
    }
```

dump is my json object. v could be an instance of entity or an array or an jQuery-object. type is the entity-type and i want to sort the values as the following.

```
dump{
   "Permission" : [ "PHONE", "SMS" ]
   "String" : [ "MN7", "AT", "DE" ]
};
```

The error i get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". And i think its because i used the identifier wrong but i don't know how to fix it if i try dump.[type].push() i get an error for missplaced [].

Comment: `dump.type` doesn't exist and isn't a method. `dump.Permission` and `dump.String` exist though ... try `dump[type].push(` instead. Notice the lack of `.` before the `[`

Comment: That fixed my missplaced [ now i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a complete reread of your situation, I think what you're looking for is something like the following:

```
addToDumpObject: function (type, v, dump) {
    if (!dump[type]) dump[type] = new Array();
    if (!$.isArray(dump[type])) return;
    else if ($.isArray(v)) for (var i in v) A.util.addToDumpObject(type, v[i], dump);
    else {
        if (v instanceof A.entity.Entity) dump[type].push(v.toString());
        else if (v instanceof jQuery) dump[type].push(v);
        else {
            if (!dump['trash']) dump.trash = new Array(); // simply for collecting other parts / debugging
            dump.trash.push(v);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: That dump was an example how the structure should look like. The problem i have. How could i ensure that the dump[type] is created as an array?

Comment: I meant if i have checked if the dumpe[type] exists and it doesn't how could i create it and ensure while created, that it is an array.

Comment: @lt_katana hmm, I'm a little puzzled. How could you create it within a method already meant to sort it? I'm not sure I follow your logic on this, but I'll reread your question and try to help you out

Comment: I hope i can unpuzzle it. The function addtodumpobject should fulfill two tasks it should sort the incoming values. But the json object is built from scratch. The object is empty at the beginning. Basically because the entitys and values are variable.

Comment: @lt_katana you can try it now,  though I'm not sure what `A.entity.Entity` should be, so that may be your next sect of errors.

Comment: You are awesome thank you very much you saved my day.

Comment: @lt_katana just doing what i can to help! glad you got it straight!